# Mute Windows Volume using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, audio, volume

Anyone know how to programmatically mute the Windows XP Volume using C#?

Comment: Is it possible in Vista/Win7?

Comment: Under Vista and above you have to use IAudioEndpointVolume.

Answer (score 16):

Declare this for P/Invoke:

```
private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE = 0x80000;
private const int WM_APPCOMMAND = 0x319;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessageW(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

And then use this line to mute/unmute the sound.

```
SendMessageW(this.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, this.Handle, (IntPtr) APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE);
```

Comment: Worked a treat in XP thanks. However I'm using WPF so there's no this.Handle. Instead:

`public static void ToggleMute(IntPtr handle)
        {
            SendMessageW(handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, handle, (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE);
        }`

In WPF Window:
`VolumeXP.ToggleMute(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);`

Comment: This ... worked on Windows 7 -- but I'm in a library, that is run in the background -- not in anything that will ever have a window -- I'm trying to mute another window -- this works -- but regardless of what I pass in for handle, (another application's window handle, etc.), it just mutes the master system volume...

Comment: Why do you use `0x80000`? `APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE` is defined as `8`? However when I use `8` it fails, but when I use your `0x80000` it works. This is odd.

Comment: Solution on why 0x80000 is given here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/40577881/1828637

Comment: nice! you can use APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP 0xA0000 instead to make sure not mute like an alarm.

Answer (score 6):

What you can use for Windows Vista/7 and probably 8 too:

You can use [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio).
Download the latest version. Extract the DLLs and reference the DLL NAudio in your C# project.

Then add the following code to iterate through all available audio devices and mute it if possible.

```
try
{
    //Instantiate an Enumerator to find audio devices
    NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator MMDE = new NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator();
    //Get all the devices, no matter what condition or status
    NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceCollection DevCol = MMDE.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(NAudio.CoreAudioApi.DataFlow.All, NAudio.CoreAudioApi.DeviceState.All);
    //Loop through all devices
    foreach (NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDevice dev in DevCol)
    {
        try
        {
            //Show us the human understandable name of the device
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(dev.FriendlyName);
            //Mute it
            dev.AudioEndpointVolume.Mute = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Do something with exception when an audio endpoint could not be muted
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //When something happend that prevent us to iterate through the devices
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This library worked when all others I've tried failed.  My problem was similar to this one, but not exactly the same.  This is a very good find.  I wish I could vote you up more than once.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote and feedback. I searched a while before I found an easy way to mute the sound. Therefore, I thought, spread the knowledge around on some stackoverflow questions :) I am glad it helped someone.

Answer (score 2):

See [How to programmatically mute the Windows XP Volume using C#?](http://alvas.net/alvas.audio,tips.aspx#tip115)

```
void SetPlayerMute(int playerMixerNo, bool value)
{
    Mixer mx = new Mixer();
    mx.MixerNo = playerMixerNo;
    DestinationLine dl = mx.GetDestination(Mixer.Playback);
    if (dl != null)
    {
        foreach (MixerControl ctrl in dl.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is MixerMuteControl)
            {
                ((MixerMuteControl)ctrl).Value = (value) ? 1 : 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly improved version of Mike de Klerks answer that doesn't require "on error resume next" code.

Step 1: Add the NAudio NuGet-package to your project (https://www.nuget.org/packages/NAudio/)

Step 2: Use this code:

```
using (var enumerator = new NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator())
{
    foreach (var device in enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(NAudio.CoreAudioApi.DataFlow.Render, NAudio.CoreAudioApi.DeviceState.Active))
    {
        if (device.AudioEndpointVolume?.HardwareSupport.HasFlag(NAudio.CoreAudioApi.EEndpointHardwareSupport.Mute) == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(device.FriendlyName);
            device.AudioEndpointVolume.Mute = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CoreAudioDevice defaultPlaybackDevice = new 
CoreAudioController().DefaultPlaybackDevice;   
        if (!defaultPlaybackDevice.IsMuted)
            defaultPlaybackDevice.ToggleMute();
```

Comment: Where does CoreAudioDevice come from?