# WPF C# mute/unmute all I/O audio devices

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, audio, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mute/unmute, Change master volume in Windows 7 x64 with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986007/mute-unmute-change-master-volume-in-windows-7-x64-with-c-sharp)

I am new to WPF and trying to find a solution to mute/unmute all microphones and all speakers on the system using a single button click. This is a personal(at home) application and I am using windows 7 64-Bit OS. I am able to find the code for mute/unmute micro phone using core audio API. But I have to mute/unmute all I/O devices.

Muting master volume will do the job? If so can anybody suggest a way to do it in WPF?

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question seems to answer your question -

[Mute/unmute, Change master volume in Windows 7 x64 with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986007/mute-unmute-change-master-volume-in-windows-7-x64-with-c-sharp)

Also take a look at this question -

[Mute Windows Volume using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154089/mute-windows-volume-using-c-sharp)

it's about WinForms but I think the solution will work for you

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will look into it and get back.