# VB.NET stop sounds in WebBrowser

Tags: vb.net

How can Stop all sounds in WebBrowser?
I'm search on internet but I couldn't found any example to stop sounds in WebBrowser.

Comment: This isn't specific to the WebBrowser control, but might get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720803/webbrowser-disable-all-audio-output-from-online-radio-to-youtube

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple answer and a simple solution.

Go to "**Control Panel**" > "Sounds and Audio Devices".

Select the "**Sounds**" tab.

Scroll down to the "**Windows Explorer**" section:

**Set the following sounds to (None):**
"Complete Navigation"
"Start Navigation"