# Why do WM_APPCOMMAND LPARAM have to be multiplied by 65536

Tags: winapi

I am trying to control the master volume. I am able to succesfully do that with this:

```
HWND mainhwnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, _T("window-noit-ext-profilist"), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, NULL, wcex.hInstance, NULL);
if (!mainhwnd) {
    MessageBox(NULL, _T("Profilist: Call to CreateWindow failed!"), _T("window-noit-ext-profilist"), NULL);
    return 1;
}


SendMessage(mainhwnd, WM_APPCOMMAND, (WPARAM)mainhwnd, (LPARAM)(APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE * 65536)); // mute

SendMessage(mainhwnd, WM_APPCOMMAND, (WPARAM)mainhwnd, (LPARAM)(APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN * 65536)); // vol down

SendMessage(mainhwnd, WM_APPCOMMAND, (WPARAM)mainhwnd, (LPARAM)(APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP * 65536)); // vol up
```

Why do I have to multiply by 65,536? The docs do not state this. IF I don't multiply, then it doesn't work.

Comment: Read the macros from the source

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For WM_APPCOMMAND, the `lParam` parameter [packs three values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646275(v=vs.85).aspx) in a single integer.

The lower 16bit word, `dwKeys`, indicates whether various virtual keys are down.

The higher 16bit word packs two fields: the highest 4 bits, `uDevice`, specifies the input device that is generating the input event. The lower 12 bits, `cmd`, contains the application command.

Multiplying by 65536 is same as bit shifting by 16 bits to the left (because 65536 = 0x10000 in hexadecimal). So, when you send the message with `APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP * 65536`, you are specifying the `cmd` is `APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP`, and the `uDevice` and `dwKeys` are both zero.